# Install Eclipse plug in from maven?

Tags: eclipse

Perhaps I am misreading, but per:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/install-plugins-mojo.html

and

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Eclipse+Plugin

Or is this meant only for RCP applications and not for an actual Eclipse IDE?

Just curious...

Thx
Misha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second link [Eclipse Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Eclipse+Plugin) actually unpack an Eclipse IDE (the RCP edition).

So it is for any Eclipse IDE distribution like the ones listed in [Helios packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).